# "Подскакивание" джойстика под палец при нажатии на экран

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно создать некое подобие джойстика для управления персонажем.
Сейчас это выглядит примерно вот так:
[image: Joystick example]
Собственно, в "закреплённом" варианте джойстик работает *почти идеально*.

Проблема же в следующем - мне нужно сделать "область", в которой джойстик будет, как-бы, подскакивать к пальцу и управляться уже из точки первого нажатия.

Я попробовал решить это следующим образом:
- Структура джойстика:
[image: Joystick structure]
- Вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и код самого "джойстика":

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class JoystickController : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, 
IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Image joystickArea,
                  joystickBackground,
                  joystick;

    private Vector2 vector;

    private void Start() 
    {
        this.joystickArea = this.GetComponent<Image> ();
        this.joystickBackground = this.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image> ();
        this.joystick = this.joystickBackground.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image> ();
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data) 
    {
        this.OnDrag(data);
    }

    public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data) 
    {
        this.vector = Vector2.zero;

        this.joystickBackground.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
        this.joystick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }

    public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData data) 
    {
        Vector2 position;

        if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(this.joystickBackground.rectTransform, data.position, data.pressEventCamera, out position)) 
        {
            position.x = (position.x / this.joystickBackground.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
            position.y = (position.y / this.joystickBackground.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

            this.vector = new Vector2(position.x * 2, position.y * 2);
            this.vector = (this.vector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? this.vector.normalized : this.vector;

            this.joystick.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2
            (
                this.vector.x * (this.joystickBackground.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 2), 
                this.vector.y * (this.joystickBackground.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 2)
            );
        }
    }

    public float horizontal() 
    {
        return this.vector.x != 0 ? this.vector.x : Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }

    public float vertical() 
    {
        return this.vector.y != 0 ? this.vector.y : Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }
}
```

Я пробовал при нажатии на экран назначать позицию для Joystick Background следующим образом:

```
public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data) 
{
    this.joystickBackground.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(data.position.x, data.position.y);

    this.OnDrag(data);
}
```

Однако на выходе получается следующее:
[image: Joystick result]

### Заранее спасибо за ответы :3

Upd: уточняю ещё раз, ориентируясь на первый ответ:
необходимо, чтобы двигалась "подложка" джойстика (joystickBackground) вместе с джойстиком (joystick) в место первого касания.
Уже сейчас оно, вроде-бы, работает "как нужно" только вот позиционирование у "подложки" постоянно разное, в зависимости от места нажатия.
Код:

```
this.joystickBackground.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(data.position.x / 2, data.position.y / 2);
```

Результат (сделал сам джойстик прозрачным оставив только "подложку" для наглядности):
[image: Test result]

Answer (score 0):

Видел я уже такой урок по джойстикам на youtube. Попробуй в строчке

```
this.vector = new Vector2(position.x * 2, position.y * 2);
```

Убрать умножение на 2, или же пропиши так :

```
this.vector = new Vector2(position.x * 2 - 1, position.y * 2 - 1);
```

Должно помочь.